# Can't see h1 tag on safari

Tags: html, css, ios

I have an issue on safari with my heading.
I use video as background.
On chrome, it has nice smooth animation, but on safari I can't even see the heading.
Can anyone find the solution? Or just the reason why it is happening?

Thanks!

Heading CSS:

```css
h1#index-title {
  font-family: 'GothamMedium', sans-serif;
  font-size: 160px;
  line-height: 0.99;
  margin-bottom: 56px;
  position: relative;
  /* background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent, #fff); */
  background: transparent;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background-blend-mode: difference;
  background: -webkit-gradient(
      linear,
      right top,
      left top,
      color-stop(50%, transparent),
      color-stop(50%, #fff)
    )
    right;
  background: -o-linear-gradient(right, transparent 50%, #fff 50%) right;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, transparent 50%, #fff 50%) right;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-size: 200% 100%;

  -webkit-animation: shownow 0.8s linear forwards;

  animation: shownow 0.8s linear forwards;
  -webkit-animation-delay: calc(var(--load-time) + 0.4s);
  animation-delay: calc(var(--load-time) + 0.4s);
}
```

Shownow animation:

```css
@-webkit-keyframes shownow {
  0% {
    background: transparent;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    background-blend-mode: difference;
    background: -webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        right top,
        left top,
        color-stop(50%, transparent),
        color-stop(50%, #fff)
      )
      right;
    background: linear-gradient(to left, transparent 50%, #fff 50%) right;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    background-size: 200% 100%;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    background-blend-mode: difference;
    background-position: left;
  }
}
```

working codepen example: https://codepen.io/tabitfree/pen/oNeOZPe

Comment: can you create a simple demo for your code?

Comment: You can't see it because the heading is white:)

Comment: I have a video as background, I didn't mention that.

Comment: Please put your code into your question as a working snippet. I see that in a comment to an answer you say you have a video as background. Are you trying to cut out the characters with the video playing through the characters only?  The video may be highly relevant. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with putting code into your question.

Comment: @AHaworth hi, here is a codepen. I have updated the question too. https://codepen.io/tabitfree/pen/oNeOZPe

Comment: I have put your code into a snippet in an 'answer' and have found that that works OK on Safari but running your codepen the video does not show. I realise the answer is not a full  explanation of the behavior but hope you can try that snippet and see whether it works for you too. What system are you normally using to run your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So.. I figured out my problem.

**DOUBLE CHECK YOUR FONT FILE.**

After approximately 6 hours of debugging and crying I've figured out that I have a corrupted font file.
Since I was desperate af I just tried to download a new font file and it worked out.

Thanks everyone for trying to help me!

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the color from #fff to #f0f:

```css
h1#index-title {
  font-family: 'GothamMedium', sans-serif;
  font-size: 160px;
  line-height: 0.99;
  margin-bottom: 56px;
  position: relative;
  /* background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent, #fff); */
  background: transparent;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background-blend-mode: difference;
  background: -webkit-gradient(
      linear,
      right top,
      left top,
      color-stop(50%, transparent),
      color-stop(50%, #fff)
    )
    right;
  background: -o-linear-gradient(right, transparent 50%, #f0f 50%) right;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, transparent 50%, #f0f 50%) right;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-size: 200% 100%;

  -webkit-animation: shownow 0.8s linear forwards;

  animation: shownow 0.8s linear forwards;
  -webkit-animation-delay: calc(var(--load-time) + 0.4s);
  animation-delay: calc(var(--load-time) + 0.4s);
}
@-webkit-keyframes shownow {
  0% {
    background: transparent;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    background-blend-mode: difference;
    background: -webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        right top,
        left top,
        color-stop(50%, transparent),
        color-stop(50%, #f0f)
      )
      right;
    background: linear-gradient(to left, transparent 50%, #f0f 50%) right;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    background-size: 200% 100%;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    background-blend-mode: difference;
    background-position: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 id="index-title">Heading</h1>
```

Comment: I have a video as background, didn't mention that. I don't have white bg. Thought that it is clear.

Comment: Okay, I just changed the color so you can see the heading is there and the animation works.

Comment: This exact code doesn't work on safari. That is the issue.

Comment: Oh, sorry I don't have Safari on my Windows machine. Perhaps somebody else could check.

Comment: Yeah, that was my issue. I mention that even in the name of this question..

Answer (score 0):

I cannot understand why the video isnt showing on your codepen but it is true, I don't see it on my Safari (IOS14 iPad).

However, using the Stackoverflow snippet system and copying the HTML and CSS from your codepen I can see the video on Safari.

Here is the snippet for you to try.

```html
<style>
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  --load-time: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  color: #fff;
}

.bg-video {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
  object-fit: cover;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -2;
}

h1#index-title {
  font-family: "GothamMedium", sans-serif;
  font-size: 160px;
  margin: 0 !important;
  line-height: 0.99;
  margin-bottom: 56px;
  position: relative;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent, #fff);
  background: transparent;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background-blend-mode: difference;
  background: -webkit-gradient(
      linear,
      right top,
      left top,
      color-stop(50%, transparent),
      color-stop(50%, #fff)
    )
    right;
  background: -o-linear-gradient(right, transparent 50%, #fff 50%) right;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, transparent 50%, #fff 50%) right;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-size: 200% 100%;

  -webkit-animation: shownow 0.8s linear forwards;

  animation: shownow 0.8s linear forwards;
  -webkit-animation-delay: calc(var(--load-time) + 0.4s);
  animation-delay: calc(var(--load-time) + 0.4s);
  margin: 0 !important;
}

@-webkit-keyframes shownow {
  0% {
    background: transparent;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    background-blend-mode: difference;
    background: -webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        right top,
        left top,
        color-stop(50%, transparent),
        color-stop(50%, #fff)
      )
      right;
    background: linear-gradient(to left, transparent 50%, #fff 50%) right;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    background-size: 200% 100%;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    background-blend-mode: difference;
    background-position: left;
  }
}

</style>
<section>
  <div class="main-container">
    <h1 id='index-title'>Long heading</h1>
  </div>
  <video class='bg-video' autoplay muted>
    <source src="http://learn.shayhowe.com/assets/misc/courses/html-css/adding-media/earth.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</section>
```

Comment: I can see the video on safari just fine. The problem is with the h1 tag.
And I am using different video on my page.

Comment: I see the h1 OK.